Why the sheaf of rings of a scheme $X$ is not a generator of the category of quasi-coherent sheaves over $X$?
Let $X$ be a scheme and denote by $\mathbf{Qcoh}(X)$ its category of quasi-coherent sheaves.
A set of generators in an abelian category $\mathcal{A}$ is a set of objects $\{U_i\}_i$ of $A$ such that for any pair of objects $M$ and $N$ from $\mathcal{A}$ and any two morphisms $f,\,g:M\to N$ there is an index $i_0$ and a morphism $h:U_{i_0}\to M$ verifying $f\circ h\neq g\circ h$. If said set has only one object, then that object is called a generator.
As stated in answers to this question, $\mathbf{Qcoh}(X)$ admits a generating set. If we take the direct sum of all the objects in said generating set, we obtain a one-object generating set, that is, a generator (so $\mathbf{Qcoh}(X)$ admits generating sets with just one object).
My question is: why the sheaf of rings $\mathcal{O}_X$ is not a generator of $\mathbf{Qcoh}(X)$? I can not come up with a counterexample of morphisms which the sheaf of rings can not distinguish.

If $\mathcal{O}_X$ is a generator, this would mean that for every $M \in \mathbf{Qcoh}(X)$ there is an epimorphism $\mathcal{O}_X^{\oplus I} \to M$, or equivalently, a jointly epimorphic family of morphisms $\mathcal{O}_X \to M$.
Notice that morphisms $\mathcal{O}_X \to M$ correspond 1:1 to global sections in $M(X)$. If $M(X) = 0$, all homomorphisms are therefore trivial and, if $M \neq 0$, there cannot be any epimorphism $\mathcal{O}_X^{\oplus I} \to M$.
An explicit example is the twisting sheaf $\mathcal{O}(-1)$ on $\mathbb{P}^1$, here every global section is zero.

Great example. What bothers me is the fact that in affine schemes, the ring and all the invirtible sheaves are generators, and thus there must be some sort of relation in the general case between generating sets and sheaves of rings somewhere

Welcome to scheme land.

Anyway, is the argument of the direct sum correct? I mean, the way to define a generator from a generating set
